# Loop to to check bluetooth adapter if it is unenable

Tags: android, loops, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy

Thanks all. 
I work with bluetooth low energy android. In service I want to check if bluetoothadapter is enable or not. If not,after every 1 minute i continue to check. If it is enable I break and do some thing.
I know how to check but I do not know how to loop and break.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your service you can create an AsyncTask, and inside create the loop:

```
private class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {

        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
        {
                    while (true) 
                    {
                                if()
                                {
                                    //it's enabled
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //it's disabled
                                }

                            Thread.sleep(60000);//millisecond to wait
                    }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            return null;
        }//end background
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
            {   

            }
    }
```